# Struggling to understand generics

Tags: java, generics

Struggling to grasp Generics. I have a parent class "Unit" which is extended by sub-classes "FootAndInch", "Mm" and "Inch".

All sub-classes share some arithmetic operations: add, subtract, division, multiply, etc... therefore it makes sense to apply generics and hopefully code once instead of duplicating code into all three sub-classes.

I assume the best place to do this is in the parent class "Unit":

```
public class Unit<T> {
    BigDecimal value;

    public Unit(BigDecimal value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValue() {
        return value;  
    }

    // First Arithmetic operation
    public <T extends Unit> T add(T measurement) {
        return value.add(measurement.getValue());
    }
}
```

The idea then is to be able to add the same measurements together:

```
Mm value1 = new Mm(20);
Mm value2 = new Mm(40);
Mm result1 = value1.add(value2);

Inch value3 = new Inch(4);
Inch value4 = new Inch(7);
Inch result2 = value3.add(value4);
```

Unfortunately I get an error from the "add" method in class Unit: "incompatible types: BigDecimal cannot be converted to T"

This makes sense but I'm unsure how to return type T

Comment: You declared two *separate* generic types but named both `T`: (1) at `class Unit<T>` and (2)  `public <T extends Unit> T add(T measurement)`. Change name of one of them to make your code (and possibly error message) more readable.

Comment: `return new Unit<>(value.add(measurement.getValue()));`, perhaps? `value.add(anotherValue)` is a `BigDecimal`, not a `T`.

Comment: Why do you want to restrict arithmetic operands to the same type? Adding 2mm to 1 inch makes perfect sense to me, the type of the result being the type of the object whose method is called. In which case you don’t need generics at all.

Comment: Weak title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: @pshemo - Thanks for your reply. Applied your suggestion and I get the  same error.

Comment: @Bohemian - Your right to some degree and I'm going to rethink this approach tonight, see if if can be implemented better. However, I'm trying to learn Generics as it's applied by java in various ways. Is the what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: @cworner1 it can be done - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have picked a gnarly example, which requires the use of a *self referencing* type.

The following compiled and runs as expected:

```
public class Unit<T extends Unit<T>> {
    BigDecimal value;

    public Unit(BigDecimal value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public BigDecimal getValue() {
        return value;  
    }

    // First Arithmetic operation
    public <U extends Unit<U>> U add(U measurement) {
        value = value.add(measurement.getValue());
        return (U)this;
    }
}

public class MM extends Unit<MM> {
    public MM(BigDecimal value) {
        super(value);
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    MM mm1 = new MM(BigDecimal.ONE);
    MM mm2 = new MM(BigDecimal.TEN);
    MM mm3 = mm1.add(mm2);
    System.out.println(mm3.getValue()); // 11
}
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/0d0K7k).

The interesting bits are:

- The type refers to itself, so subclasses can be captured by T when T extends Unit
- BigDecimal is immutable. Calling its `add()` method does nothing to it; rather it returns the result as a new BigDecimal
- A cast was needed for add()’s return

Comment: Brilliant! I'll study this in detail in the next couple of nights - thank you!

Comment: I've finally got my head round this, very clever! Thanks again.

Comment: @cworner1 this example by makes the same mistake as you did: introducing a second type parameter `T` for the method which hides the type parameter `T` at the class level.  Therefore this will also compile if you try to add Inches.  But it will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime since in that case the `T` in the method is `Inch` while the instance has type `MM`.  In order to fix this, the `<T extends Unit<T>>` in the `add` method signature must be removed.

Comment: @herman Good point. I removed the type shadowing and updated the live demo, which compiles and runs OK.

Comment: @Bohemian I'm sorry but you still got it wrong.  Yes you removed the type shadowing, but code that tries to add two different subtypes of `Unit` will still compile, but fail at runtime.  The goal of generics is to improve type safety so that failing code will not compile.  Like I said, you just needed to remove the additional `T`, not introduce a new type parameter `U`.  The type that gets passed to the `add` method must be the same as `this` (so `T`) and the return type of that method also.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a type parameter `T` at the class level and `T extends Unit` at the method level.  These are different `T`'s.  If you'd really need both, it would be wise to give them different names.  But my guess is the type parameter at the class level shouldn't be there, since in `T extends Unit` you're using the raw type `Unit` (i.e. without type parameter).

Second, your `Unit` class and subclasses don't just represent the units themselves, but values in a specific unit.  Apart from the naming issue, you should think about whether you actually need these types, or can just have a type `Measurement` that stores it's internal value in mm but has static factory methods such as

`static Measurement ofInches(BigDecimal inches) {...}`

`static Measurement ofFeetAndInches(BigDecimal feet, BigDecimal inches) {...}`

etc. which construct the `Measurement` using the proper conversion to the internal mm value.  Then the `add` method simply has to sum the internal values.
This is exactly the approach taken by the `java.time.Duration` class which has static methods `ofDays(long days)`, `ofHours(long hours)` etc. and has a method `plus(Duration duration)` which sums the internal values (split into seconds and nanos for precision, but that is beside the point).  It also has methods `toDays()`, `toHours()` etc. to convert to different units.

Comment: You right in what you're staying. It could be design differently/better. However I'm looking to understand Generics so I'm trying to apply it to this particular piece of code (despite it not being the best way when looking at the bigger picture. I wondered how/if the code could be adapted to adopt Generics. If I could analyse working code it might help me understand it better.

Comment: I think I understand Class generics and understand a working example with ArrayList<>. I guess it's the method part I'm struggling with.